# Javascript: Split File into an Array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of english words in a [text file](http://www.desiquintans.com/downloads/nounlist/nounlist.txt). I would like to create an array from this file separated by words:

```
var dictionaryWords = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Strawberry"]
```

How can I use do this in javascript? and please try to explain in beginner terms since I'm still new to this! Thanks!

Comment: You may ask server-side a hand...

Comment: Is it always one word per row, or can it be more words per row? Aka.: "this file is separated by words" -- you probably mean new lines? (Which then means exactly one word per line.)

Comment: Is this JavaScript in the browser, or something like node.js? If not node what are you using on the server side?

Comment: Im using it on a browser. Im just trying to make a hangman game that takes a word from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the file contents in a variable, you use the `split()` method to split it into an array:

```
var dictionary = file_contents.split("\n");
```

`\n` is the newline character.

You can use AJAX to read the file from the server into a Javascript variable. There are many AJAX tutorials on the web, I'm not going to try to teach that here.

Comment: This is not the full answer: he also needs to know how to read the file (at least that is how I understand the question). I'm not the downvoter btw.

Comment: @Attilio Well, I'm not going to try to turn this answer into a tutorial on how to use AJAX. I added something to the answer telling him that's the direction he needs to go.

Comment: @Attilio Given the information available I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree, with the addition of the pointer to AJAX, it answers the whole question, as far as I understand it...